# How to add new plugin to babel.config.js when env/production is already there?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, babeljs

In my React Native project, my `babel.config.js` currently looks like this:

```
module.exports = {
  presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
  env: {
    production: {
      plugins: ['react-native-paper/babel'],
    },
  },
};
```

I need to add `react-native-reanimated/plugin` to `plugins`, but I don't know how to add a `plugins` array that isn't under `env.production` when there's already the `env.production.plugins` array. How should I approach this?

Answer (score 0):

you can use this sample

```
production: {
  plugins: ['react-native-paper/babel', 'transform-remove-console'],
},
```

If that is what you mean, add new plugins you can use this

```
module.exports = {

 presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset']

  env: {
production: {
  plugins: ['react-native-paper/babel', 'transform-remove-console'],
            },
       },
plugins: [.....],
};
```